# .Net Core 3.0 Routing With React

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net-core

Using `.Net Core 3.0 preview 7 with React` (Create-React-App), I've published a basic SPA. The site works well, except for when it comes to routing.

The problem is that entering a URL directly re-routes everything to the main page (Index). That is, when navigating to `www.mysite.com/Topic?query=Topic1` directly, a URL I know exists, the site redirects to `www.mysite.com`.

From my research, I understand that Client & Server-Side Rendering are not the same. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually) SO post articulates that well. It's also clear that when manually entering in a URL, you're directing your request to the Server, not the Client, i.e. React Router doesn't yet exist, so the route's been sent to the server.

What isn't clear is the fix.

From what I can tell, I need to configure my `UseMVC` routes in `Startup.cs`. [This](https://code-maze.com/routing-asp-net-core-mvc/)  article explains the idea, but not how to accomplish it with React. Routing to an *action* is all well and good, but how do you route to a Client-side *page*?

As a sample, here's the default routing:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

What I've tried is this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Topic",
        template: "{controller=Topic}/{action=Get}/{topicName}");

});
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything. I'm not even sure it's in the right place, either...

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work, but you can try to map the [`MapSpaFallbackRoute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.sparouteextensions.mapspafallbackroute?view=aspnetcore-3.0) extension to your main index file and then immediately activate your _React_ routing from within that file. In my testing of the extension listed above, mapping the route did not rewrite the url so the _React Router_ should successfully pick it up.

Comment: Interesting idea. Let me look into it.